# Init of Class with constructor with non mandatory values

Tags: powershell

this class

```
class Test {
    [string]$Path
    Test([string]$p){ $this.Path = $p}
}
```

can be initialized e.g. with

```
[Test]$t1 = [Test]::new("\data")
```

using an empty Path as in

```
[Test]$t3 = [Test]::new()
$t3.Path = "\tempfolder3\data"
```

does fails with

```
The property 'Path' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
```

Is there a way in PowerShell to have a class with a none mandatory constructor ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructor chaining in PowerShell - call other constructors in the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413206/constructor-chaining-in-powershell-call-other-constructors-in-the-same-class)

Comment: Note that the error message is not consistent with your code. As written, it is `[Test]::new()` that  would throw an error, namely `Cannot find an overload for "new" and the argument count: "0".`

Comment: thanks for your answers but actually the error messages was as stated and overloading the constructor as suggested by eikenyo did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this;

```
class Test {
    [string]$Path

    Test([string]$p){ $this.Path = $p}
    # Overload constructor:
    Test(){ }
}

[Test]$t1 = [Test]::new("\data")

Write-Host "t1:"
Write-Host $t1.Path

[Test]$t2 = [Test]::new()
$t2.Path = "\tempfolder3\data"

Write-Host "t2:"
Write-Host $t2.Path
```